# Changing values in a local scope

Tags: c, scope

Does anyone know of a way I can change the values of variables that are defined locally?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int change(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;

    change(x,y);
    printf("x:%d y:%d\n", x, y);
}

int change(int x, int y)
{
    x = 20;
    y = 30;

    return(x);
    return(y);
}
```

I want x and y to print 20 and 30 in main().
I tried returning the values, but that didn't work. Is there another method I might be able to use? I was thinking pointers, but I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pointers:

```
void change(int *x, int *y)
{
    *x = 20;
    *y = 30;
}
```

and call the function like: `change(&x, &y);` For readability you may want to use different names than `x` and `y` for the `change` parameters as they are not of the same type as the `x` and `y` variables declared in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1) Pass by refernce: `int change(int &x, int &y);`

2) Return an array and change current values:

```
int* temp = new int[2];
temp[0]=x+10;
temp[1]=y+10;
return temp;
```

3) Return to printf directly:

```
printf("x:%d y:%d\n", change(x,y)[0], change(x,y)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it's very easy 
just pass the parameters by reference to the change function
so instead of
int change(int x, int y)  > 
int change(int& x, int& y)
and it will works fine